# Django - how to filter though multiple manyTomany relationship layers

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-filter

Consider the following setup:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    foreign = models.ForeignKey(ModelB, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    children = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name="parent", symmetrical=False, blank=True)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=50, null=False, unique=True)
    children = models.ManyToManyField(ModelC, blank=True)

class ModelC(models.Model):
    ...lots of fields
```

Now, given the pk of a ModelA Object, I want to get and filter all the related ModelC Objects. Here is what i'm trying to achieve efficiently:

```
modelC_objects = ModelA.objects.get(pk=modelA_id).children.foreign.children
    .filter(pk__lte=last_id)      
    .exclude(is_private=True)
    .order_by('-pk')[0:100]
    .prefetch_related("other")
)
```

Obviously that doesn't work. I am currently doing something ugly like this:

```
modelA_objects = ModelA.objects.get(pk=modelA_id).children
modelC_querysets = [modelA.foreign.children for modelA in modelA_objects]
if modelC_querysets:
    modelC_objects = modelC_querysets[0]
    modelC_querysets.pop(0)
    for x in modelC_querysets:                    
        modelC_objects = modelC_objects | x
filtered = (modelC_objects.filter(pk__lte=last_id)      
   .exclude(is_private=True)
   .order_by('-pk')[0:100]
   .prefetch_related("other")
)
```

How can I achieve what I attempted?

Comment: I don't understand: You say you have the pk of a modelA object, i.e. you have the object (`a = ModelA.objects.get(pk=pk)`). Then the related C objects are `a.foreign.children.all()`.

Comment: The problem is ModelA is recursive `ManyToManyField('self')`. So it's not just `a.foreign.children`, it's `a.foreign.children` for each `a` that has pk=pk as parent.

Comment: So when you say “related” C objects you mean related directly to the a object but also related via any of the descendants or ascendants of a? Ie if a1 is a grandfather to a you also want those related C objects? Your query example is only looking at direct children, not even a itself is included. You need to clarify your question with an example.

Comment: I edited my code for more clarity. As you can see, I clearly need `modelA.foreign.children` on many `modelA` objects. The problem is that I cannot do this: `ModelA.objects.get(pk=modelA_id).children.foreign.children` since accessing each `.foreign` after `ModelA.objects.get(pk=modelA_id).children` is impossible :(

Comment: So you’re only looking at the direct children of a?  and a itself isn’t included?

Comment: It would be better if I could include a itself, but I can work with only its children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to get `ModelC` objects, so you need to start your query on `ModelC`. But it would also help if you name the reverse relationships in your models so that it's easier to traverse in the opposite direction:

```
class modelA:
    foreign = models.ForeignKey(ModelB, related_name='modelAs' on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class modelB:
    children = models.ManyToManyField(ModelC, related_name='parents')
    ...

modelA_qs = ModelA.objects.filter(Q(id=pk) | Q(parents__id=pk))
modelC_objects = ModelC.objects.filter(parents__modelAs__in=modelA_qs)
```

The first `parents` refers to the `ModelB` objects that are parents to a `ModelC` object, then `modelAs` fetches the `ModelA` objects for each of them. You probably should add a `distinct()` clause at the end, because you'll very likely get duplicate `modelC` objects.

Comment: Tested and it works exactly as expected, thank you very much. This statement helped me a lot to improve my logic: _You want to get ModelC objects, so you need to start your query on ModelC_ One question though. How does this work in terms of efficiency? Imagine I have 300 Million `ModelC` objects, and this query would return only about 2000 objects, is this method efficient?