# Get information from many to many fields in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

My model:

```
class User_Detail(models.Model):
 username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=False)
 email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False)
 password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 auth_token = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, null=True)


class Board(models.Model):
 unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=True)
 created_by = models.ForeignKey(User_Detail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="board_creator")
 name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=
True)


# membership
class UserBoardMapping(models.Model):
 user = models.ManyToManyField(User_Detail)
 board = models.ManyToManyField(Board)
 user_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=USER_TYPE, default='moderator')
```

How can I get all the users who are `members` of a particular board id? I want user information in my output with the board id.

Comment: Use dunder and Q for filtering. It should solve your problem.

Comment: can you add a solution, which can help me understand

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58982940/django-how-to-filter-though-multiple-manytomany-relationship-layers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your model structure is not right. Because you are using 2 many to many relation to map between User and Board, where one should be sufficient. If you want to store additional information like `is_moderator`, then try like this with [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through).

```
class User_Detail(models.Model):
 username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=False)
 email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False)
 password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 auth_token = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, null=True)


class Board(models.Model):
 unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=True)
 created_by = models.ForeignKey(User_Detail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="board_creator")
 name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=
True)
 users = models.ManyToManyField(User_Detail, through='UserBoardMapping')


# membership
class UserBoardMapping(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(User_Detail, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='boards')
 board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='users')
 user_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=USER_TYPE, default='moderator')
```

Then you can query `User_Detail` for a `Board` like this:

```
board = Board.objects.first()
users = User_Detail.objects.filter(boards__board=board)
```

Comment: how to add the user who created the board as a moderator

Comment: You can create a signal on which you will add request.user as moderator. You can check if there is any member exists in the board, if not create a UserBoardMapping instance with is_moderator True.